# How scalable is Bcrypt for a Rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I know the whole point of Bcrypt is to be time expensive when hashing to limit practicality of a brute force attack. But, doesn't that make it inherently unscalable? For instance, one site I read was claiming that the cost factor in Bcrypt should be adjusted so that a hash takes 0.25 seconds on the current hardware. If you had a moderately successful site with even a few hundred people logging in at any time does that 0.25 seconds compound making every user potentially have top wait several seconds? Does the server's CPU max out when hashing for the 0.25 seconds causing constant high resource usage?

As a secondary question, assuming it is scalable (which I'm sure it is), what is an appropriate cost factor these days?

Comment: If you have a *moderate* successful site with *a few hundred users* logging in *at the same time*, you will need a couple of servers anyway... Short answer: Nope this will not be the bottleneck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more appropriate for one of the other Stackoverflow sites as it will promote discussion and isn't a specific programming question.

That said, the first issue you raise would most likely be addressed by using a service that could be scaled as required to serve concurrent authentication requests to provide an acceptable response time for the end user.  One way to do this would be to have multiple servers behind a load balancer, with authentication requests routed to the load balancer for hand-off to the authentication servers.  Individual authentication requests would run on essentially random servers, and provided your system architecture was correct it would be seamless from the point of view of the client.

Comment: Is bcrypt significantly less scalable than any other hashing algorithm though?

Comment: Not necessarily, it might just have a higher resource requirement than other methods.